# Systemd-resolved service stopping unexpectedly

Tags: fedora, systemd-resolved

Almost every day, sometimes more than once a day, Systemd-resolved crashes on my fedora machine.

Output: https://pastebin.com/sgN3C0BU (I removed some stuff which I did not know if it was safe to share).

The last part of the output:

```
Feb 13 15:27:30 pluto systemd-resolved[107209]: malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected
Feb 13 15:27:30 pluto systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Feb 13 15:27:30 pluto systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Feb 13 15:27:30 pluto systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 9.
Feb 13 15:27:30 pluto systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Feb 13 15:27:30 pluto systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 13 15:27:30 pluto systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Feb 13 15:27:30 pluto systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
```

Some details:
my Machine is running Fedora 33, nothing else special which I can think to mention. I have looked at similar posts about the issue, but I could not determine what is going on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: fixed for now by switching to Unbound https://blobfolio.com/2017/fix-linux-dns-issues-caused-by-systemd-resolved/

Comment: You might file a bug report or build the latest upstream systemd yourself instead of using Fedora's.